# Set image src url to a blob

Tags: javascript, html, image, request, blob

I want to create a functionality like the Telegram Web.
[Telegram Image Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJWnV.png)
The image src is set to a blob url but how this blob created ?
[Network Tab Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXIof.png)
when I check the network tab, I found only requests related to blobs.

I did try to set the url of image as blob but it doesn't work

```
const img = document.querySelector("#img1")
const blob = new Blob(['https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/3/5000/3333.jpg?hmac=GDjZ2uNWE3V59PkdDaOzTOuV3tPWWxJSf4fNcxu4S2g'], {type: "text/plain"})
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
img.setAttribute("src", url)
```

I dont want to show image request in network tab